# Different rubocop outputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

Right now rubocop is giving me 3 different outputs regarding my rails project, depending on how I invoke it.

```
> rubocop # version: 0.34.2
88 files inspected, 5 offenses detected

>bundle exec rubocop # version: 0.30.1
87 files inspected, no offenses detected

>rake # with :rubocop in my task list
87 files inspected, 35 offenses detected

>bundle exec rake # with :rubocop in my task list
87 files inspected, 35 offenses detected
```

2 variations makes sense, since my system rubocop version is different from the one in my Gemfile . But **3**? wuuuut?

I'm assuming the 3rd output is coming from a third version of rubocop somewhere? Where would it be? What's going on here?

**Update:**

Task list: `['ci:setup', :spec, :rubocop, :jshint, 'brakeman:run', 'bundler:audit', 'bundler:outdated']`

**Update 2:**

On the advice of a collegue I dropped this in to try to get the running rubocop version during rake:

```
task :rubocop do
  require 'rubocop/rake_task'
  require 'rubocop/version'
  puts RuboCop::Version.version
  RuboCop::RakeTask.new do |task|
    task.patterns = ['--rails']
  end
end
```

That prints `0.30.1`, the version I expect. Still no explanation of the errors.

Comment: What are your other rake tasks? Is something generated that RuboCop could pick up on?

Comment: @Drenmi I've added the list of tasks that get run. If there are files being generated / altered during rake I'd assume that subsequent runs of `rubocop` / `bundle exec rubocop` would catch them? (That's not happening.)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is sad and embarrassing.

If I had looked more closely at the rake task for rubocop I would have noticed:

```
task.patterns = ['--rails']
```

Which adds some extra cops. Adding that flag to `bundle exec rubocop --rails` matches with the output from a `rake` run.

I hope this helps someone else notice this faster than I did.